# Reload Page for new Page Message

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction, action

I have below page snippet where after facet execution to "stop" , I need a page reload. Currently it's not happening hence retaining older page message. Can someone please guide me?

Page Snippet:

```
<apex:tab label="HCI/HCO Calls" >
                        <apex:pageBlockTable id="HCIHCO" columns="9" value="{!oIncTranListHCI}" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >
                            <div class="page-break" >
                            </div>
                            <apex:column headerValue="Incident ID ">
                                <apex:outputLink value="/{!itr.Id}">{!itr.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column value="{!itr.Account_abv__c}"/>
                            <!--      <apex:column value="{!itr.Call_abv__c}"/>            -->
                            <apex:column value="{!itr.Product_abv__c}"/>
                            <apex:column value="{!itr.Time_of_Event_ABS_abv__c}"/>
                            <apex:column value="{!itr.Audit_Reason_abv__c}"/>
                            <apex:column headerValue="Transaction Type" value="{!itr.Transaction_Type_abv__c}"/>
                            <apex:column headerValue="Outcome" >
                                <apex:actionRegion >
                                    <apex:actionStatus id="SaveStatus">
                                        <apex:facet name="start"  >                                            
                                            <apex:outputText value="Saving...!" />
                                        </apex:facet>
                                        <apex:facet name="stop"  >
                                            <apex:image url="/img/msg_icons/confirm16.png" title="Saved Successfully" rendered="{!itr.Id == targetId}" />
                                        </apex:facet>

                                    </apex:actionstatus>
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" onchange="jsCallSave('{!itr.Id}','{!itr.Transaction_Type_abv__c}');"  rendered="{!Compliance_Incident_abv__c.Confirm_Attestation_abv__c == false}">
                                    </apex:inputField>
                                    <apex:inputField label="Transaction Type" value="{!itr.Transaction_Type_abv__c}" style="display:none;"/>
                                </apex:actionRegion>
                                <apex:outputField value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" rendered="{!Compliance_Incident_abv__c.Confirm_Attestation_abv__c == true}"/>
                            </apex:column>
                        </apex:pageBlockTable>
                    </apex:tab>
```

Comment: Can you post the code where the SaveStatus actionStatus is called. If that is having a reRender it will reRender the intended block. Else you need to add to it.